# Calculate two points of triangle with given Z

Tags: c#, xna, geometry, intersection, monogame

I want to calculate the two points of a 3D triangle that have a specified Z coordinate. I guess the way to do this would be to somehow create a plane which is perfectly flat with my given Z coordinate and then calculate where the triangle intersects with it (or is this wrong).

If you know how to do this in any way please help. I have searched for but have not really found anything that seems to work.

Comment: What code have you tried? And how can you find a triangle knowing only one point? I must be misunderstanding you, but there is no possible way to calculate a triangle with just one (or even two) points, and not other info.

Comment: I'm with davidsbro here, please add more info, I'm not sure what you are talking about.

Comment: I have the 3 points, but I want a the two points of the sides of the triangle that have a given z coordinate

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your triangle is defined by three points where T0 is base left, T1 is base right and T2 is tip.
And a lot of other assumptions about how the triangle is aligned etc:

```
public bool GetIntersect(Vector3 T0, Vector3 T1, Vector3 T2, float Z, out Vector3 P0, out Vector3 P1)
{
    if (!((Z <= T2.Z) && (Z >= T0.Z) && (Z >= T1.Z)))
        return false;

    var left = T2 - T0;
    left *= 1f / left.Z;

    var right = T2 - T1;
    right * 1f / right.Z;

    P0 = T0 + (left * (Z - T0.Z));
    P1 = T1 + (right * (Z - T1.Z));

    return true;
}
```

P.S; Uppercase in parameter names are bad! don't do that! I just don't care to fix my mistake right now :P

Comment: Sorry, this does not work on complex models. Could you please elaborate more on the orientation that the triangles need to have?

Comment: It assumes that T0.Z and T1.Z are <= Z, and that T2.Z > Z. So the more your triangle is aligned to the XY-plane, the better. If it doesn't work then, I am very sorry, and I must have made a mistake :(